# Find all roots of a polynomial with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, solver, polynomials

As an example, I want to find all five roots of the polynomial `x**3 * (x - 3)**2`.

sympy's `solve` command finds a `0` and a `3`:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols ('x')
solve (x**3 * (x - 3)**2)

[0, 3]
```

According to the fundamental theorem of algebra, I would have hoped that `solve` honored the multiplicity of the roots and returned something like

```
[0, 0, 0, 3, 3]
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any parameter that would persuade `solve` or other solvers like `solveset`, `nonlinsolve`, and `nsolve` to return a list of five elements. Fortunately, sympy's `roots` returns a dictionary indicating the multiplicity:

```
r = roots (x**3 * (x - 3)**2); r

{3: 2, 0: 3}
```

Is there an easy way to transform this dictionary into the desired list of five elements? I came up with

```
l = []
for k, v in r.items ():
    for m in range (v):
        l.append (k)
l

[3, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

but I feel like there should be a more elegant way ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `multiple` argument to `roots`:

```
In [91]: roots(x**3 * (x - 3)**2)
Out[91]: {0: 3, 3: 2}

In [92]: roots(x**3 * (x - 3)**2, multiple=True)
Out[92]: [0, 0, 0, 3, 3]
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyroots.roots

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more elegant solution:

```
a = []
[a.extend([k]*v) for k, v in r.items()]
print(a)
```

Comment: Slim solution! Since I am pretty new to python I did not know you could generate multiple entries in a list via `[k]*v`. How do you call that kind of construct and where can I learn about it?

Comment: That sort of thing is covered fairly early in the official tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: `[n]*m` creates an m-element list filled with elements of value n. For example, `[2]*5 = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`. According to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234887/what-is-the-x-mn-syntax-in-python), one could call it "sequence repetition," but it is pretty much an overloaded multiplication operator.

Comment: You can also use a double `for` loop as in `a = [k for k, v in r.items() for _ in range(v)]`. Or, shorter, `a = [k for k in r for _ in range(r[k])]`